# Recurring alarm BroadcastReceiver Intent string extras not getting updated

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have the below class to check if my alarms are being triggered at the exact time which I scheduled or is it differing.

I will call SetAlarm method inside the BroadCast Reciever from MainActivity. The consecutive alarms will be set by the Receiver itself by setting current time as its new string extra.

Alarms are working fine except the issue Intent string extras are not getting updated. ScheduledTime will always hold the initial value regardless of what I have set it in the setAlarm method.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Date currentTime = new Date(); 
        String ScheduledTime = ""; 
        if (null != intent) { //Null Checking
            ScheduledTime =   intent.getStringExtra("ScheduledTime");
            //intent.removeExtra("ScheduledTime");
        }
        String message  = "Current Time" + currentTime + ",  Scheduled Time was: " + ScheduledTime ; 
        //Show Notification 

        long alarmMillis =(10*60*1000) ; //Set Alarm after 10 minutes
        Long newTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() +  alarmMillis;
        currentTime.setTime(newTimeInMillis );
        setAlarm(context, newTimeInMillis , currentTime.toString());
    }

     public void setAlarm(Context context, Long timeMillis, String ScheduledTime)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        i.putExtra("ScheduledTime", ScheduledTime);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeMillis, pi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Android official site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

> `public static final int FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`
>
> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists,
>   then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new
>   Intent. For use with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int),
>   getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int,
>   Intent, int).
>
> This can be used if you are creating intents where only the extras
>   change, and don't care that any entities that received your previous
>   PendingIntent will be able to launch it with your new extras even if
>   they are not explicitly given to it.

So change your code from

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
```

to

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```